# PostGIS; won't update geometry when importing CSV file with psql

Tags: postgis

I installed PostgreSQL 12 and PostGIS on a new server.
I want to use this environment as source for different projects and services.

When I try to import CSV files in the database using psql, I get an error when trying to execute the following:

```
UPDATE bet_srk_2020 SET geom = 
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(AISTrajectPositionLongitude, 
AISTrajectPositionLatitude) ,4326);
```

Result:

```
FATAL:  failed to load summary "/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/bitcode/postgis-3.index.bc": Invalid summary version 7, 1, 2, 3 or 4 expected
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

I tried to find information about this error but can't really find solutions.

I am able to add data to the databases if I use the QGIS Toolbox feature:
Export to PostgreSQL

Is this simply a syntax error in my request to the server? Or is there a problem with the installation of PostGIS?

EDIT: 2020 10 30:

Based on CL. comments I investigated the problem in my installation:
I use a Ubuntu setup with the apt.postgresql.org repository.

For some reason Postgresql-12 was installed from the postgresql.org repository and postGIS 3.0 was installed from the standard Ubuntu repository. After installing postGIS from the same repo as postgreSQL the problem was solved and server operation is back to normal.

Comment: Looks like an installation problem. Did you compile it yourself, or use some package?

Comment: Use packages in apt (Ubuntu) but i did use a different repository than Ubuntu’s own

Comment: What's wrong with the official repo?

Comment: @CL. Followed guide that applied apt.postgresql.org

Comment: Did you mix PostgreSQL and PostGIS from different repos? Do you really need something newer than what is in the Ubuntu repo?

Comment: that acutally was the problem! for some reason PostgreSQL was installed from the postgresql.org repo and postGIS from the Ubuntu repo. Using the latest version on a new setup was just something that seemed the right thing to do.

Comment: Sweet! Could you post that as answer yourself? :)

Comment: Please post the answer [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was caused due to installation of postgreSQL-12 and postGIS from different repositories in Ubuntu-server.
the postgresql-12 was installed via the apt.postgresql.org repo.
the postGIS was installed via the standard Ubuntu repo.

After postGIS was installed via the same repo the errors no longer occurred